# Powershell: Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DifferenceObject' because it is null

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, office365

I'm trying to compare AD users list with distribution list (O365). **Foreach** loop give me results as expected:

```
$AD = @($(Get-ADuser -Filter *).UserPrincipalName)
$DL = @($(Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Everyone").WindowsLiveId)
ForEach ($name in $AD) {if ($DL -notcontains $name) {Write-Output $name}}
```

But when I'm trying to use Compare-Object command:

```
$AD = @($(get-aduser -Filter *).UserPrincipalName)
$DL = @($(Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Everyone").WindowsLiveId)
Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $AD -ReferenceObject $DL
```

Console giving me error:

```
Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DifferenceObject' because it is null.
At line:1 char:34
+ Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $AD -ReferenceObject $DL
+                                  ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObjectCommand
```

Do you have any ideas why Compare-Object complaining on $AD array. It is definitely not null and not empty.

Comment: `Compare-Object` doesn't work like you think it does. Use foreach loop for what you're trying to do

Comment: but it is working for this: **Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity userA) -DifferenceObject $(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity userB)**

Comment: Yes, because those two objects have the **exact same properties**

Comment: Also consider to use the `Where-Object`: `$AD | ? {$_ -notin $DL}`

Comment: Thanks @iRon that works with where.

Comment: @KolobCanyon, the output are serialized into two arrays, both of them has  email addresses inside. But looks like they are not exact the same as you wrote above. So I'm just wondering how to serialize $AD to the same format as $DL.